Meaning of “having” + ⟨past participle⟩
Can I ask for clarification when to use “having” + ⟨past participle⟩?
For example: “Having lived in Prague, I know where to find a good restaurant”
In this case I don’t understand why the having clause is used and not the simple “Because I lived in Prague, I know…”
Is there any difference in meaning?

They are practically the same in meaning. Because introduces a cause and effect. Having introduces a fact: Since this is true; With this fact in mind, Considering this.

I. Using  Participles to join sentences.
OP's first query:

can I ask for clarification when to use Having + past participle verb?
For example - “Having lived in Prague, I know where to find a good restaurant”

Both Present participle (V+ing) and Perfect participles (Having + Past participle) can be used to join two sentences.
You can write more intelligent, interesting, and complex writing that clearly communicates your thoughts and the relationships between them by using participles to combine sentences. Therefore, if you aspire to be a writer, you need become proficient in the art of using this.
II. How to join sentences using Participles..
Explanation from a grammar book
Ref. Adventures with Grammar and Composition, Beena Sugatham. Oxford Printing Press..

Participles can also be used to join pairs of sentences.
.
1.When two sentences state facts, we convert the verb of the less important sentence into a participle.
For example:
Sam spent three hours in the library. He was writing his essay.
Sam spent three hours in the library writing his essay.
.
2.If the two sentences talk about two actions happening one after the other in succession we change the verb of the first action into a present participle.
For example:
He opened the window. He looked out.
Opening the window, he looked out..
Nina ran to the nearest store. She bought the medicine.
Running to the nearest store, Nina bought the medicine..
.
3.If one action was completed sometime before the other we use having + past participle form of the verb of the first action. This is called a perfect participle.
We use a comma to separate the two parts of the sentences.
Rajeev took a bath. He sat down to study.
Having taken a bath, Rajeev sat down to study..
Maria finished reading the book. She wrote a book review on it.
Having finished reading the book, Maria wrote a book review on it.

III. Why Participles are used to join sentences..

In this case I don’t understand why the having clause is used and not simple -
“Because I lived in Prague, I know….”
or is there any difference in meaning?

Participles help link two states or events together by implying that one is the result of the other.
You  break up the monotony of simple sentence forms and give your work more variation by joining sentences with participles.

They both mean the same thing. One uses an adverb clause of reason (causality) and the other uses a reduced adverb clause of reason (warning: grammar terms vary):
Here’s an adverb clause:

Because I lived in Prague, I know where to find a good restaurant.

Here it is reduced:

Having lived in Prague, I know where to find a good restaurant.

See ThoughtCo: What Are Reduced Adverb Clauses and How Do They Work? 

That's an excellent reference for a construction which I've noticed to be one that perpetually puzzles English learners.

Thank you for clarification
